# 50 Ohm impedance RF transmission line PCB design

Tags: pcb, antenna, impedance, bluetooth

I am designing a PCB for a Bluetooth 5 device using Qualcomm chip and a Murata BP filter. The RF circuit is composed of:

- an SMT antenna that has a 50 Ohm unbalanced feed point impedance,
- a Murata 2.45GHz Bandpass filter that has a characteristic nominal impedance of 50 Ohm
- a BT IC which has a 50 Ohm port impedance for BT_RF.

Below is the design guidelines from the SMT antenna datasheet:
[image: Matching network for SMT antenna]

**ANTENNA**>>---*(1 w/ P1&P2)*--->>**BP Filt**>>---*(2 w/ Pi-LC)*--->>**BT_RF**

With all these components having a 50 Ohm impedance, how should I design the PCB traces (1) and (2) and their matching networks? Should (1) and (2) individually have a 50 Ohm impedance or should the whole transmission line from SMT antenna feed point to BT_RF have a 50 Ohm impedance?

Answer (score 1):

If Qualcomm or Murata has a reference layout that would be a good starting point - it appears you have this. Generally you want to use 50 ohm routing for everything. Use microstrip with guard grounds surrounding it, as shown in the reference.

Comment: And make sure to work with the board house. They can tell you the precise trace geometries to get 50 Ohms in their process with your board specs.